# Training Haar classifier to detect letters/digits

Tags: opencv, ocr

I have a test answer sheet with circled answers and I am trying to detect digits/letters using OpenCV. I used 10x10 image of '2' as positive image and 44 other parts of the answer sheet as negatives to create Haar classifier myself.

Apparently, I am doing something wrong as my classifier fails to detect original '2'.

```
$opencv_createsamples -vec a_desc.bin -info positive.txt -bg negative.txt -num 1 -w 10 -h 10

$opencv_traincascade -data classifiers -vec a_desc.bin -bg negative.txt -numStages 20 -numPos 1 -numNeg 46 -w 10 -h 10
....

    ===== TRAINING 4-stage =====
    <BEGIN
    POS count : consumed   1 : 1
    NEG count : acceptanceRatio    0 : 0
    Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.
```

What I am doing wrong:

- too fee negatives
- too few positives
- size of negatives and positives must match
- all images must be in the same format (png | jpg | gif)

Basically, what the expectation for the following approach:

1. A page from random books is selected
2. We create 10x10 image of 'e' letter
3. We create 20 negative images of other letters/digits
4. We create a classifier using these two datasets
5. Now we try to classify the original page.

Are we supposed to supposed to find ALL occurrences of 'e' and some false positives?

Comment: how are people supposed to help you without you providing your code? And post your training and test data too. You may get better answers on stats or data science stackexchange.

Comment: And for Haar classifier (Haar  AdaBoost) are recommended thousands of samples.

Comment: I ended up using TensorFlow and increases my dataset size.